# What are global forwards in Struts 2?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

What are global forwards in Struts 2, and how do they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blog](http://struts2-examples.blogspot.com/) gives examples of global forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Think of global forwards as generic results or common forwards like error pages that display generic error messages for all actions or login forwards for members only pages, etc.
They are independent of individual actions and can be called from any action. Apart from that, they will work just like normal forwards.